# find all characters between first and last

Tags: regex

To be more specific: I want to find everything between the first and last `*`:

```
\*\*KEMPE\*\* TM0001 hydraulic leak \*TECO\*Repair Slag Pot 59 \*\*TECO\*\*\* Scaffold removal Acid Plant At \*CAL A\*
```

i.e.

```
\*\*KEMPE\*\*, \*TECO\*, \*\*TECO\*\*\*, \*CAL A\*
```

Comment: this: `\*+[^*]+\*+`

Comment: Does the text you're matching contain all those backslashes?

Comment: no, i added them because markdown was formatting the `*` as bold

Comment: Yep, That works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

with `grep`

```
echo "**KEMPE** TM0001 hydraulic leak *TECO*Repair Slag Pot 59 **TECO*** Scaffold removal Acid Plant At *CAL A*" | 
grep -oE '\*+[^*]+\*+' | xargs

**KEMPE** *TECO* **TECO*** *CAL A*
```